# How to download an RPM package and install it in one line?

Tags: pipe, rpm, wget

I was wondering whether using `wget` it was possible to download an RPM and then pipe it through `sudo rpm -i` to install it, in a single line? I realize I could just run:

```
wget -c <URL>
sudo rpm -i <PACKAGE-NAME>.rpm
```

to install the package but I was wondering whether it might be possible to do this in a single line using the quiet and write to standard output options of wget. I have tried using:

```
wget -cqO- <URL> | sudo rpm -i
```

but it returned:

```
rpm: no packages given for install
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo rpm -i <URL>`?

Comment: Have you tried `wget -cqO- <URL> | xargs  sudo rpm -i` or maybe `sudo rpm -i $(wget -cqO- <URL>)`? What error do they give?

Comment: @Firelord. 1st command: just gave it a try and it gave the error shown [here](http://paste2.org/Vg6cxk60). 2nd command: gave the error `rpm: no packages given for install`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

RPM has native support to download a package from a URL. You can do:

```
sudo rpm -i <URL>
```

There is no need to download the RPM manually. If this support didn't exist, you could use `bash`'s process substitution.

```
sudo bash -c 'rpm -i <(wget -O - <URL>)'
```

Comment: It's better to use yum install -y <URL>, because it will also install any dependencies.

Comment: Well if I were using a distro that uses yum as its package manager it would, but remember RPM packages are also used by distros that use APT-RPM, DNF, urpmi and ZYpp package managers. Turns out I was using openSUSE Tumbleweed, which uses ZYpp.

Answer (score 22):

Better to do `yum install -y <URL>` as this does alto take care of dependencies, as opposed to direct `rpm` tool use.

Comment: As I said in the comments on jordanm's answer I was using openSUSE Tumbleweed, yum isn't available on Tumbleweed.

Comment: Lol @sorin *yum is not available wtf*.

Answer (score 2):

I guess one possible way could be to define the filename of what you are downloading:

```
wget -cqO- <URL> -O my-output-file.rpm && sudo rpm -i my-output-file.rpm
```

But surely there must be better approaches

Comment: I won't accept this answer as (as you said) I'm hoping for better approaches but, you know this is a good attempt, so thanks.

Comment: @JoshPinto this is not a good approach, it is the only correct answer..

Answer (score 0):

Another way when you want to install with `rpm` becuase `dnf` won't let you do bad things (like use `--nodeps`):

```
rpm -i --nodeps  $(dnf download --quiet --url somepackage-version-1 )
```

You may also need to do `dnf install -y 'dnf-command(download)'`